# Make Windows Server 2003 DHCP exclude a certain MAC

Tags: dhcp, pxe-boot, windows-server-2003-r2, windows-server-2003

how can i refuse to assign an IP to a certain mac-address? or the other way round: how can i let the DHCP-server assign an IP only to some very special mac-addresses?

i'm running two DHCP-servers on the same physical network - not good, i know that. but i need to boot a machine using PXE and the dhcp-server should assign addresses only to this machine, and not touch the others.

the other machines receive an ip by the router. that one doesn't support adding a special dhcp-option which itself is required for PXE-boot.

the server in question is a windows server 2003 R2 SP2 with the DHCP-services installed.

i clicked around and looked for answers on the internet - without big success.

thanks in advance and best regards
atmocreations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might help

[How to Filter MAC Address with Windows Server 2003/2008 DHCP Server Callout DLL](http://www.petri.co.il/filter-mac-address-windows-server-2008-dhcp-server-callout-dll.htm)

Comment: very clever way
thanks. good tip! that one seems to work.
unfortunately this solves only part of the problem. my router sucks: either the mac receives an ip from the router (which shouldn't distribute any) or the mac is blocked for all traffic (mac-filtering). well, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Limit the scope on the one DHCP server to only the PXE MAC addresses.  That way it won't assign IPs to any other machines except the ones that use PXE.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's easier than this.  You can set up DHCP on the 2008 box to ONLY serve out PXE requests.  So long as you can keep the router from assigning the addresses you want to give to PXE clients, all should be well.

It should be buried in the DHCP server options.  Don't have one handy atm, but leave a note if you need a hand.

Comment: But the title states this is for Server 2003, not 2008.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my part - I've set this up with my 2003 DHCP server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the DNS server to *only* assign addresses to certain macs, setup the range with *no* available address. (Yes none) then use the reservations to assign the macs you want to allow in there.

Edit: You can do the other way around by using reservations with invalid ip addresses. We do this to stop certain machines connecting to our network at times. I'm not sure how it might affect you since you do need them to connect but a quick test will show you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a scope with a range of one address. Set a reservation for that address to be assigned to the MAC address you want to use. Of course that won't stop your PXE machine from getting its IP address from the router if that answers the request first.